# return in jQuery.each

Tags: jquery

can i have the implmentation for jQuery.each wherein if i find any match within the array which is been processed in jQuery.each, then i can break / return without further process the remaining elements.

```
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
```

You can select the list items and iterate across them:

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  //if($(this).text() == 'foo') , i.e if foo is found , 
//then return instead of processing bar.
});
```

Comment: You should consider reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) when you have questions like this: "_We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return false` does that :

```
var elem;

$( "li" ).each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'foo') {
        elem = this;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, Short explanation. And returning false means `break` and returning true means `continue`

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation.

We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

**Example:**

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>

<script>

    var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
    jQuery.each(arr, function() {
        $("#" + this).text("Mine is " + this + ".");
        return (this != "three"); // will stop running after "three"
    });

</script>`
```